# How to speed up appending to a multi-index DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, numba

I'm using apply on a multi-index groupby with Numba and found that the slowest part is adding the results back to the original frame. How would I achieve this with speeds that are practical? The indexes in the original df are unique.

Import and generate some data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numba

times =             np.arange(datetime(2017, 1, 1), datetime(2020, 2, 1), timedelta(minutes=60)).astype(np.datetime64)
tlen =              len(times)
A, Z =              np.array(['A', 'Z']).view('int32')
symbol_names =      np.random.randint(low=A, high=Z, size=50 * 7, dtype='int32').view(f'U{7}')
times =             np.concatenate([times] * 50)
names =             np.array([y for x in [[s] * tlen for s in symbol_names] for y in x])
open_column =       np.random.randint(low=40, high=60, size=len(times), dtype='uint32')
high_column =       np.random.randint(low=50, high=70, size=len(times), dtype='uint32')
low_column =        np.random.randint(low=30, high=50, size=len(times), dtype='uint32')
close_column =      np.random.randint(low=40, high=60, size=len(times), dtype='uint32')
df = pd.DataFrame({'open': open_column, 'high': high_column, 'low': low_column, 'close': close_column}, index=[names, times])
df.index = df.index.set_names(['Symbol', 'Date'])
df['entry'] = np.select( [df.open > df.open.shift(), False], (df.close, -1), np.nan)
df['exit'] =  df.close.where(df.high > df.open * 1.33, np.nan)
```

Define the numba function:

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def nb_func(arr, limit=0, stop=0, tbe=0):
    is_active = 0
    bars_held = 0
    limit_target = np.inf
    stop_target = -np.inf
    result = np.empty(arr.shape[0], dtype='float32')

    for n in range(arr.shape[0]):
        ret = 0
        if is_active == 1:
            bars_held += 1
            if arr[n][2] < stop_target:
                ret = stop_target
                is_active = 0
            elif arr[n][1] > limit_target:
                ret = limit_target
                is_active = 0
            elif bars_held >= tbe:
                ret = arr[n][3]
                is_active = 0
            elif arr[n][5] > 0:
                ret = arr[n][3]
                is_active = 0
        if is_active == 0:
            if arr[n][4] > 0:
                is_active = 1
                bars_held = 0
                if stop != 0:
                    stop_target = arr[n][3] * stop
                if limit != 0:
                    limit_target = arr[n][3] * limit
        result[n] = ret
    return result
```

Define the applied function with additional arguments and create the groupBy object:

```
def process(group):
    group['result'] = nb_func(group.values, limit=1.10, stop=0.50, tbe=5)
    return group['result']

group = df[['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'entry', 'exit']].groupby('Symbol')
```

Using regular concat the result is extremely slow:

```
def concat(group):
    ret = group.apply(*[process]).droplevel(0)
    df2 = pd.concat([df, ret], axis=1)

concat(group)
>> concat function took 20.292 s
```

Adding the result back as a column is faster but still slow:

```
def simple_readd(group):
    ret = group.apply(*[process]).droplevel(0)
    df['result'] = ret
    
simple_readd(group)
>> simple_readd function took 7.141 s
```

Calculating the results without adding them back to the original frame is fast and I'd like to get the total time to around 1 s:

```
def series_return(group):
    ret = group.apply(*[process]).droplevel(0)

series_return(group)
>> series_return function took 0.905 s
```

**UPDATE:**
This is the most improvement in time I've managed, from 7 seconds to about 1.8. Still interested in doing better as the indexes and columns are completely identical, perhaps there is a numPy solution?

```
def series_merge(group):
    ret = group.apply(*[process]).droplevel(0)
    merged = df.reset_index().merge(ret, on=['Symbol', 'Date'], how='left').reset_index(drop=True)
    merged = merged.set_index(['Symbol', 'Date'])
    return merged

series_merge(group)
>> series_merge function took 1.892 s
```